# Can an I2C sensor be destroyed by connecting SCL to a wrong GPIO pin?

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, gpio

Is it possible to break an I2C sensor by connecting the SCL to SDA, or GPI04 to Ground accidentally? Could accidentally connecting SDA to 3V3 do the same? After a cable broke, one of these things could have happened. The sensor now does not respond with any value, and i2cdetect does not find the sensor any more. Are there ways to verify what is broken?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does the picture show that is relevant to your question?

Comment: Yes, connecting 3.3V to SDA and/or SCL will make the sensor and/or host pull transistor short-circuit as soon they try to communicate. It's a matter of line resistance and luck which component fails.

Comment: Can you tell the type of sensor? Maybe there is a way to find the problem without  communication. Did you conect 3V3 to all pins or made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The data and clock pins on a I2C slave are open drain. This means that they will only pull the line to ground.

So if you connected 3.3V without a current limiter to one of the pins and it tried to pull the line low then it can damage the transistor and make the pin useless.